# Authenticating Google RCS Business Messaging API's

Tags: google-api-client

I am trying to send RCS campaign messages to google android messages client, for that I looked here https://developers.google.com/business-communications/rcs-business-messaging/guides/get-started/first-agent#send_a_message and trying to use the curl command provided here to send "Hello World" text to my number. I have service account key JSON file and using this I am trying to access this send API's, but I am getting OAuth2l command not found error as shown below.

To access this google RBM API's should I need to generate any access token and use this token as bearer to do above curl request.

Anyone please let me know how to authenticate these google RBM API's. I am working on it from so many day's but no luck. Thanks in advance.

[OAuth2l not found error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xB5v7.png)

I tried to generate the access token using JWT by looking this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=91PlQyrebbk and used this token as bearer in the API call but no luck. There I got 403 error as shown below.

Am I doing the right way to send RCS campaign messages on Android messages client using service account key file.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
                "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
                "domain": "googleapis.com",
                "metadata": {
                    "method": "google.communications.rcsbusinessmessaging.v1.RcsBusinessMessagingService.GetCapabilities",
                    "service": "rcsbusinessmessaging.googleapis.com"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Using service account credentials we need to generate the jwt access token which expires every 60mins, in turn use this token to authenticate these google RCS business messaging API's .Finally I am able to authenticate the API's. Thanks.

Comment: Docs make it seem like tokens and token refreshing ought to be done automatically with google-auth package [see here](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-auth/latest/user-guide.html#service-account-private-key-files) However, to make it work you needed to generate access tokens manually? I've been stuck here, so I'd love it if you could elaborate @Deepak K T

Comment: In java example, it relies on google-auth-library-oauth2-http. You can pass the json credential files to it and generates JWT programmatically. I believe it serves the same function as oauth2l

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the OAuth2l commandline tool, it can be found [here](https://github.com/google/oauth2l)